# How to detect phone call coming

Tags: c#, windows-phone

In window phone sdk,we can ovveride the windows back button.But I don't know how to detect phone call coming or ovverride phone call event.Please hepl me.Thanks

Comment: As far as I know, this is not possible. The phone handles these, and (luckily) apps cannot override the behavior.

Comment: I don't think it is possible, and in my opinion it shouldn't be possible.

Answer (score 1):

[There is no way 3rd party apps can intercept incoming phone call in windows phone 8 currently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13176545/windows-phone-8-support-to-capture-sms-or-a-incoming-call).

The best you can get is [Obsecured](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.controls.phoneapplicationframe.obscured%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) event. That event raised when your application in foreground and intercepted by incoming call, reminder, or any other system event taking the screen from application. Nothing more.

Anyway, that event too, is not intended to bring developer closer to be able to intercept incoming call.

Answer (score 0):

The current Windows Phone SDK doesn't allow you to access any information about received/dropped calls, nor their log information...

I guess that you would have to use with Interop access to achieve such a thing, but that is always tricky!